# MVC4 Model state is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having trouble posting in my mvc4 + EF6 project. The model from the view is populated with all the fields except the Year and Period (they are dropdown list fields). In the view model attached to the view the fields Year and Period are not set to be required with DataAnnotations. However when I try to post, the ModelState is invalid.

How do I determine what cause of the ModelState being invalid?

See code below:

HTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Status)
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Edit Performance Cycle Details</legend>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Year, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                @Html.DropDownList("Year", new SelectList(ViewBag.Years), "--- Select Cycle Year ---", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Year" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Period, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                @Html.DropDownList("Period", new SelectList(ViewBag.Period, "Id", "Title"), "--- Select Period ---", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Period" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, "EditorForCycleSD")
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CloseDate, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CloseDate, "EditorForCycleCD")
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Cycle", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            }
```

Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "StartDate, CloseDate, Id, Status")] EditCycle cycleUpdate, string Year, string Period)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int yearPost = Int32.Parse(Year);
                string periodPost = Period.Trim();
                switch (periodPost)
                {
                    case "1":
                        periodPost = yearPost.ToString() + " - H1";
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        periodPost = yearPost.ToString() + " - H2";
                        break;
                    default:
                        return View(cycleUpdate);
                }
                int pf = Int32.Parse(User.Identity.Name.Substring(8));

                cycleUpdate.Year = yearPost;
                cycleUpdate.Period = periodPost;
                if (this.repo.EditCycle(cycleUpdate, pf))
                {
                    return View("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    List<CyclePeriod> period = new List<CyclePeriod>{
                        new CyclePeriod {Id=1, Title="First Half : January 1 - June 30"},
                        new CyclePeriod {Id=2, Title="Second Half : July 1 - December 31"}
                    };

                    int[] years = new int[5];
                    for (int i = (DateTime.Now.Year - 2), j = 0; i <= (DateTime.Now.Year + 2); i++, j++)
                    {
                        years[j] = i;
                    }

                    ViewBag.Years = years;
                    ViewBag.Period = period;

                    return View(cycleUpdate);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                List<CyclePeriod> period = new List<CyclePeriod>{
                    new CyclePeriod {Id=1, Title="First Half : January 1 - June 30"},
                    new CyclePeriod {Id=2, Title="Second Half : July 1 - December 31"}
                };

                int[] years = new int[5];
                for (int i = (DateTime.Now.Year - 2), j = 0; i <= (DateTime.Now.Year + 2); i++, j++)
                {
                    years[j] = i;
                }

                ViewBag.Years = years;
                ViewBag.Period = period;

                return View(cycleUpdate);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            List<CyclePeriod> period = new List<CyclePeriod>{
                    new CyclePeriod {Id=1, Title="First Half : January 1 - June 30"},
                    new CyclePeriod {Id=2, Title="Second Half : July 1 - December 31"}
                };

            int[] years = new int[5];
            for (int i = (DateTime.Now.Year - 2), j = 0; i <= (DateTime.Now.Year + 2); i++, j++)
            {
                years[j] = i;
            }

            ViewBag.Years = years;
            ViewBag.Period = period;

            return View(cycleUpdate);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can check in the ModelState object the property error which contains a collection

Comment: Or put a ValidationSummary() in the view so that you can see the error message(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the year and period are of type int this means they can't be null (therefore required). In order to avoid this you have to use int? (Nullable)

Comment: A non-nullable int won't cause the required validator to mark the field as invalid. The model value will already be default(T) for value types.

Answer (score 21):

I agree with Tibi. You probably want to use nullable types.

> "How do I determine what cause of the ModelState being invalid?"

This will get you a list of keys (which are the property names from your model) with their errors from ModelState:

```
var errors = ModelState.Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Any())
                .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors });
```

Comment: Finally foud out what was my error, Thanks, it save my day !

Comment: Perfect solution @Mr. B. You saved my lot's of time.